# Reshape the dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Music dataset. Where two columns ('Music_id' and 'Tag_name' ) are there.
Sample data:

```
Music_id       Tag_name
  1004         Base Guitar
  1004         Guitar
  2004         Base guitar
  1005         Keyboard
  1003         Keyboard
  1004         Keyboard
```

I want to reshape this dataframe where all `tag_name` should become the column name, so that every row should have unique `Music_id`.

I read about the concept of stratification and merging but not sure how to apply in this situation. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question not clear. Maybe give us what you expect output to be

I guess you need this?

```
pd.crosstab(df.Music_id, df.Tag_name, dropna=False)
```

[image]